# Change Website Contact Address depending on user location

Tags: wordpress

I have a company that is catering to 3 different markets:
The US, Bermuda, and the UK. Is it possible to update the business address to reflect the location the user is from? For instance if they are accessing the site from Bermuda it shows the Bermuda address and phone number. If from the UK it will show the UK address and phone number and so on.

Comment: google for geolocation ip services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various [geolocation/geotargeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotargeting) services you can purchase (where you use an API to submit the user's IP address and receive their country – or town - back.)  It will involve programming and also means you'd need to disable any caching you were using on any pages using geolocation.

You'd need to decide how you were going to handle search engines - which contact details should be shown in the search results?

Additionally, you can't guarantee the country will be accurate if someone uses a proxy server, corporate VPN etc. (e.g. personal experience: accessing the internet over a mobile phone or public wi-fi in the UK sometimes gives you an IP address in a different country entirely). Geolocation providers try  to keep on top of this but there are mistakes.

You may find it more practical to simply divide the site up into separate directory trees for each market (e.g. `www.example.com/uk/contact-us`) or list all the contact details on the same page.